# Jasperstarter exception on run

Tags: jasperstarter

I have made report in Jaspersoft studio and it runs without any problem.

Trying to run it from latest jasperstarter:

```
JasperStarter 3.5.0-java7 Rev 76746ab (JasperStarter-3.5.0-java7)
 - JasperReports: 6.4.0
```

It produces error:

```
usr@usr-VirtualBox:~/SHARED/PlotJSON$ /home/usr/jasperstarter/bin/jasperstarter pr -t json --data-file plotdata Glavni.jrxml -f pdf -r .
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from InputStream.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedObjectPersistenceService.load(SerializedObjectPersistenceService.java:60)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedReportPersistenceService.load(SerializedReportPersistenceService.java:40)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:144)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:112)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:398)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:365)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:427)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:341)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterNewPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1179)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1029)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:286)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.Report.fillInternal(Report.java:326)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.Report.fill(Report.java:282)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.processReport(App.java:226)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.main(App.java:109)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from InputStream.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:290)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedObjectPersistenceService.load(SerializedObjectPersistenceService.java:56)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:737)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:89)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1829)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2120)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2365)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2289)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2147)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2365)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2289)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2147)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:278)
    ... 25 more
```

Can anyone please give a hint what to do to remedy this situation.

Are there some jar files I should copy from Studio to jasperstarter to make it work?